# validate input using try catch

Tags: java, if-statement, try-catch

I am trying to validate input text field in java by creating an exceptional error if user does not type in the word specified i.e. admin

```
        String username;
        int phone1;

        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {          
            try
            {
            phone1 = Integer.parseInt(phone.getText());
            }
            catch (Exception exe)
            {           
                MessageDialog.openError(shell, "Error","Phone number has to be a number");
                return;
            }

            try
            {
            username = namefield.getText();
               if (username!= "admin") {
                    throw (new Exception());
                }           
            }
            catch (Exception exe)
            {   
                MessageDialog.openError(shell, "Error","The username must be admin");
                return;
            }


            labelresult.setText("The name entered is:"+ username );


            labelresult2.setText("The phone entered is:"+ phone1 );
```

The one for phone works perfectly

What about for username. What should i do?

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam that does not answer my question completely. since i am talking about try catch.

Comment: Are you sure the execution is reaching the throw statement.

Comment: It's generally recommended not to use exceptions to control program flow.

Comment: @simonv i understand it is not recommended. i am in a situation that i have to use it. so i have simplified my question so as to understand try catch statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @simonv mentioned in comment, Don't use exception to control program flow. But if you are learning `try-catch`, than you can try this. Also improve your `if` statement. You are comparing string object. So use `equals()` method as following:

```
        try
        {
        username = namefield.getText();
           if (!"admin".equals(username)) {
                throw new Exception("YOUR_MESSAGE_HERE");
            }           
        }
        catch (Exception exe)
        {   
            System.out.println(exe);
            return;
        }
```

Comment: I believe it should be .equals...not .equal

Comment: yes It is .equals() @krushiovida

Answer (score 2):

You should use:

```
 if(!username.equals("admin")){
 //your code
 }
```

To compare string you will have to use `equals()` method.

As suggested by simon, it is recommended to use:

```
if(!"admin".equals(username)){
 // your code 
}
```

In that way it will be null safe.

Comment: I would recommend reversing this equals check to avoid potential null pointers.